# How to run a specific profile on WebSphere on Docker?

Tags: java, linux, docker, websphere, websphere-traditional

Is it possible to copy an existing WebSphere profile and run it on WebSphere in Docker?

I am doing some research on containerization, virtualization, etc. and am currently working with Docker. Getting WebSphere up and running on Docker is simple enough:

```
 docker run --name wasserver -h wasserver -p 9043:9043 -p 9443:9443 -d ibmcom/websphere-traditional:install
```

What I'd like to do is use a profile from another WebSphere instance and run that on the Docker WebSphere. I have tried to do the following in an attempt to mount a directory that contains the profile in question, and to run same:

```
docker run -v /opt/WebSphere/WAS8_5/:/WASDIR --name myprofileserver -h myprofileserver -p 9043:9043 -p 9443:9443 -d ibmcom/websphere-traditional:install -e PROFILE_NAME=/WASDIR/profiles/myprofile1
```

The end result of this command is that the container is created, but does not run:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: exec: "-e": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Perhaps there is a switch, setup, or other configuration I am missing here?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Doesn't look a good fit for either of those @jww and the answers in that last link all say DevOps questions should generally be posted on SO. There are loads of questions / answers about Docker and a good user knowledgebase about it on SO. The platform itself is directly relevant to programming and development so can you elaborate on the off-topic designation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last argument to `docker run` is the command you want to run inside the container (or the name of the image if you're running the default `entrypoint` / `cmd`). You just need to move your environment variable definition back in the command like this:

`docker run -v /opt/WebSphere/WAS8_5/:/WASDIR --name myprofileserver -h myprofileserver -p 9043:9043 -p 9443:9443 -d -e PROFILE_NAME=/WASDIR/profiles/myprofile1 ibmcom/websphere-traditional:install`

Comment: Thanks for the input - this certainly has helped, though I'm still not up and running.